# Rails Admin actions in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have a sensitive civic involvement Rails app. In it's Rails Admin I have disabled the delete and bulk_delete actions.
In rails_admin.rb I have something like

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    show
    edit
    # delete
    # bulk_delete
  end
end
```

How can I override this behaviour for specific models, for example, SitePosts? I have tried using the "rails_admin do" block in the model, but it is not working obviously.

```
rails_admin do
  configure :site_post do
    actions do
      new
      show
      edit
      delete
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `only` method for enabling actions for specific models. For instance, in your `rails_admin.rb`:

```
config.actions do
  dashboard                     # mandatory
  index                         # mandatory
  new
  delete do
    only SitePost
  end
end
```

The `only` and `except` methods are documented in the wiki under [Base action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-action).